# Android update webview every 5 seconds

Tags: java, android

Here is my code. It fires the first time but then stops. I would like it to repeat.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                     int i = 0;
                    String[] myStrings = { "http://192.168.1.199/jax.html", "http://192.168.1.199/jor.html" };
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        webView.loadUrl(myStrings[i]);
                        i++;
                        if (i ==2)
                            i = 0;
                    }
                }, 5000);
```

Comment: you need to call postDelayed method again inside of run method to make your code works every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will cause your runnable to repeat. It calls itself every 5 seconds.

```
final int TIME_BETWEEN_RELOAD = 5000;
final Handler myHandler = new Handler();


final Runnable reloadWebViewRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d("run", "running the runnable now");
        // Continue the reload every 5 seconds
        myHandler.postDelayed(this, TIME_BETWEEN_RELOAD);

    }
};
// start the initial reload
myHandler.postDelayed(reloadWebViewRunnable, TIME_BETWEEN_RELOAD);
```

Comment: Perfect Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are using `postDelayed` function wrongly. Post delayed is meant to be used to run something after a specified number of milliseconds. From Android Documentaion

```
postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis)
```

> Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue, to be run
>   after the specified amount of time elapses.

Ofcourse your code will run only for the first time. All you are doing is adding a 5 second delay to it.

If you want to fire something after regular intervals consider using a [Count Down Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) or an [Alarm Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

If you really want to use `postDelayed` you can do this

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
int delay = 5000; //milliseconds

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        //do something
        handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
    }
}, delay);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the handler.postDelayed(runnable) again inside the run() function of the runnable. If you do it how you're currently doing it, it indeed will call it only once, because that is what you are telling it to do.

So I'd suggest creating a variable for the handler and another for the runnable, instead of using the *new Handler(){}* and *new Runnable(){}*, in this case, just to make it easier. So you'd have something like this:

```
    Handler webHandler;
    Runnable webRunnable;   
    //some other code in here you might have - remember to instantiate the handler

    webRunnable = new Runnable(){
            int i = 0;
            String[] myStrings = { "http://192.168.1.199/jax.html", "http://192.168.1.199/jor.html" };
            @Override
            public void run() {
                webView.loadUrl(myStrings[i]);
                i++;
                if (i ==2)
                    i = 0;
            webHandler.postDelayed(webRunnable, 5000);
            }
     };
     webHandler.postDelayed(webRunnable, 5000);
```

Thus, calling the postDelayed like this, once outside the run() function, and then inside, it will run the runnable, then it calls itself again over and over, after 5 seconds